# Mine and other players skins not loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I can't see skins anymore. Everyone including myself is either a Steve or an Alex. I've tried looking up solutions and asking friends, but nothing is working. I think this started around 1.9-something. No matter what I try I can't get skins to work. I've relogged, reinstalled Minecraft multiple times, changing my skin, and using texture packs. Nothing I've tried fixes it. Any nerds know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

these are some ways that it should maybe work.

1. change to an older version and change skin in the minecraft website. after it, change to version 1.10.2
2. be sure you saved the skin.
3. be sure the skin image is 64 x 64 pixel wide.
4. some textures pack dosen't show the skin. i recommend you to use faithful 32 x 32.

if it didn't work, im sorry but i cant find other tips.